# mvn jetty:run failing Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/javax/xml/bind/ModuleUtil.class

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to perform an `mvn jetty:run` on my project, however, the process keeps failing and I can't get the project running locally. From the error stack trace, I think a relevant one to focus on is `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/javax/xml/bind/ModuleUtil.class from jar file:///C:/Users/Tabish/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar`. I have tried changing the versions of jaxb but to no avail.

Here is the error trace

```java
[WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@4998e74b{/myntra-v4-proxy,[file:///C:/Users/Tabish/Documents/Increff/Code/proxies/myntra-v4-proxy/target/webapp-tmp/, jar:file:///C:/Users/Tabish/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/2.4.0/springfox-swagger-ui-2.4.0.jar!/META-INF/resources],STARTING}{file:///C:/Users/Tabish/Documents/Increff/Code/proxies/myntra-v4-proxy/target/webapp-tmp/}
org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations (AnnotationConfiguration.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure (AnnotationConfiguration.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure (WebAppContext.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart (ServletContextHandler.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart (JettyWebAppContext.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart (ContextHandlerCollection.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start (Server.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart (Server.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty (AbstractJettyMojo.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute (AbstractJettyMojo.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute (JettyRunMojo.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar (AnnotationParser.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse (AnnotationParser.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call (AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run (AnnotationConfiguration.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/javax/xml/bind/ModuleUtil.class from jar file:///C:/Users/Tabish/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar (AnnotationParser.java:937)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse (AnnotationParser.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call (AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run (AnnotationConfiguration.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass (AnnotationParser.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry (AnnotationParser.java:984)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar (AnnotationParser.java:933)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse (AnnotationParser.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call (AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run (AnnotationConfiguration.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@721bf7ad{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:9000}
[INFO] Started @31575ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

I am running with jdk-11.0.2. My pom.xml has the following dependencies and jetty plugin (one of which is causing the problem, I think)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        </dependency>
...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
            </plugin>
...
```

How can I fix this to allow my project to run on the local machine?

Comment: Seems to be due to jdk version and library version not compatible, you can take a look to the [source](https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/-/blob/f7f44a8e306dd2bd70f0db50194f6366938579c5/src/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.java#L160).Which jdk you are using?

Comment: @samabcde What library version are you referring to? Also, I am using jdk-11.0.2.

Comment: What is your jetty version?

Comment: @samabcde Jetty is 9.3.7.v20160115

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. By referring to [pom of jaxb-api/2.3.0](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.pom), the target jdk version is 9.
2. By finding the dependency of [jetty-annotations/9.3.7.v20160115](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-annotations/9.3.7.v20160115), the dependency for
   "org.ow2.asm/asm" is [5.0.1](http://5.0.1)
   As JDK 9 is release in September 2017, it is quite certain that the asm library will not support java 9, we can also refer to source code for `ClassReader`

```java
public class ClassReader {
...
    /**
     * Constructs a new {@link ClassReader} object.
     * 
     * @param b
     *            the bytecode of the class to be read.
     * @param off
     *            the start offset of the class data.
     * @param len
     *            the length of the class data.
     */
    public ClassReader(final byte[] b, final int off, final int len) {
        this.b = b;
        // checks the class version
        if (readShort(off + 6) > Opcodes.V1_8) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
...
}
```

We see that the class version is checked if the version is later than 1.8.
Following program show how to check if the jar contain class not supported for `ClassReader`.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;

public class ClassReaderJarVersionCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        checkClassVersion();
    }

    private static void checkClassVersion() {

        String jarPath = "{path_to_jar}\\jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar";
        try (JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(jarPath)) {
            jarFile.stream().forEach(jarEntry -> {
                if (jarEntry.isDirectory() || !jarEntry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                    return;
                }
                int version = -1;
                try {
                    byte[] byteArray = toByteArray(jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry));
                    version = readShort(byteArray, 6);
                    new ClassReader(byteArray);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    System.out.println(jarEntry.getName() + " version: " + version);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }

    private static short readShort(byte[] b, int index) {
        return (short) (((b[index] & 0xFF) << 8) | (b[index + 1] & 0xFF));
    }

    private static byte[] toByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
        }
        buffer.flush();
        byte[] byteArray = buffer.toByteArray();
        return byteArray;
    }
}
```

### Solution

### Upgrade Jetty for JDK>=11

By referring to [jetty 9.4.12 release announcement](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jetty-announce/msg00124.html), update the dependency of jetty to [version 9.4.12](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/9.4.12.v20180830) to support JDK 11 should solve the problem.

### Downgrade jaxb-api for JDK 8

Use version 2.2.11 as the [next version 2.3.0 start adopting JDK 9](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch02.html#a-2-3-0)

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I am using JDK 1.8 and getting the same error , How can i fix it in local ?

Comment: @Vasanth, if you can't upgrade to jdk 11 and update the jetty version, please post another question with dependency and other necessary information.

Comment: @Vasanth, I added solution for jdk 8, please check if this resolve your problem.

Comment: its works for me . <jetty.version>9.4.36.v20210114</jetty.version>. thank you for your reference.